# SEPolicy for multiple services using AIDL in Android Native

Tags: android, selinux, aidl, android-binder, seandroid

I want to add multiple services with:

```
MyService sv1 = MyService::getInstance(mode::mode1);
defaultServiceManager()->addService(String16("Service1"), sv1);
MyService sv2 = MyService::getInstance(mode::mode2);
defaultServiceManager()->addService(String16("Service2"), sv2);
```

And here are my sepolicy files:

**myservice.te:**

```
type myservice, domain, coredomain;
```

**service.te**

```
type my_service, system_api_service, service_manager_type;
```

I want to register 2 services with different name, so I added these in **service_contexts**

```
Service1 u:object_r:my_service:s0
Service2 u:object_r:my_service:s0
```

But when I run, the logcat return avc error:

```
E SELinux : avc:  denied  { add } for pid=431 uid=1000 name=Service1 scontext=u:r:myservice:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=1
```

I think Service1 and Service2 did not registered to servicemanager, so avd shows **default_android_service** in tcontext.

How can I register my own services in sepolicy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a reference service to check, but maybe you only forgot to use `binder_use` and `add_service`.

```
type myservice, domain, coredomain;
type my_service, system_api_service, service_manager_type;

# Allow myservice to use binder
binder_use(myservice)

# Allow myservice to add the service "my_service"
add_service(myservice, my_service)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added binder_use and add_service, I want 2 services: Service1 and Service2 can be add by defaultServiceManager()->addService but SEPolicy was denied. My question is how can I use 2 different service's names in one type?

Comment: Do you still get the same ne

Comment: Do you still get the same message from avc?

Comment: Yes, it stills denied  add name=Service1  and name=Service2